# progress bar in list activity

Tags: android

please help me how can i put the progress bar in the following code . This code is basically fetching the list  from the server so what i want that before appearing the list from the server  progress bar should appear for the waiting time bcz it takes some time to fetch the list from the server

Here is the code

```
 public class Test extends ListActivity  {
          Prefs myprefs = null;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);
            this.myprefs = new Prefs(getApplicationContext());
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://midsweden.gofreeserve.com/fetch.php?id=" + 
                    Test.this.myprefs.getEmail());

            try{

                JSONArray  earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("earthquakes");

                for(int i=0;i<earthquakes.length();i++){                        
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
                    JSONObject e = earthquakes.getJSONObject(i);

                    map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
                    map.put("name", "Earthquake name:" + e.getString("name"));
                    map.put("password", "Magnitude: " +  e.getString("password"));
                    mylist.add(map);            
                }       
            }catch(JSONException e)        {
                 Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
            }

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.test, 
                            new String[] { "name", "magnitude" }, 
                            new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

            setListAdapter(adapter);

            final ListView lv = getListView();
            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
                    Toast.makeText(Test.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

                }
            });
        }



        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.settings:     
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowSettings.class);
                      startActivity(intent);
                break;
                case R.id.services:     
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Test.class);
                    startActivity(intent2);
                  break;
                case R.id.Quit: 

                    finish();



                    break;
                default:    
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Admittedly I'm not following your logic, but the crash is almost certainly due to the `workthread.start();` since you've never set workthread to anything. That's your NullPointerException.

Comment: @ColdForged After removing the 'workthread.start()' now dialog box is appearing and the list is also appearing. but all  processing is not getting stopped although the list haas been appeard

Comment: Well, again I'm not following the logic of your application. Or your question, really. I _assume_ you meant to have some kind of workerthread that processed the JSON asynchronously and posted updates to the progress dialog. Once complete you'd remove the dialog? As it stands, you create the dialog, do the JSON processing in the main UI thread and then set the list view up. I'd read up on threading (http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html). If you just want your dialog gone, call `myprogress.dismiss()` after your JSON processing is complete.

Comment: @ColdForged i have updated it with the original code . i simply want to put the progress bar in it b4 the list appear .

Comment: What you're asking is not simple. You need to rearchitect your application and put your JSON loading into a different method, like an `AsyncTask` as in the link I gave you. The problem is you're doing _everything_ in the main UI thread. You open your progress dialog, then start pulling JSON, then display your list, all synchronously in your single UI thread. That won't work for what you want.

Comment: Ah now it seems much more clear to me . I got some idea . Thanks for the guidance

Answer (score 0):

Always avoid long running operation on your mail `Ui thread`. One of the best way to do long running operation is - Use `AsynTask` to do long running operation(e.g., requesting data from server & downloading something from internet etc.,). Please read [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), 
You may do it like this_

```
public class Test extends ListActivity  {
    Prefs myprefs = null;


  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);
      this.myprefs = new Prefs(getApplicationContext());
      ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
      final ListView lv = getListView();
      setListAdapter(adapter);

      //Execute long running operation.
      new GetListDataAndShowProgress().execute();

      lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
              @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
              HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
              Toast.makeText(Test.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

          }
      });
  }

  //Your all other code.....

}
```

And here is your class that load data from server.

```
class GetListDataAndShowProgress extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

    ProgressDialog loadingDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        loadingDialog = new ProgressDialog(Test.this);
        loadingDialog.setTitle("Fetching Data!");
        loadingDialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
        loadingDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        loadingDialog.setCancelable(false);
        loadingDialog.show();

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Your code that fetch data from server and add into your ArrayList

        return "Success to  get List data!";
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        loadingDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(Test.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

I hope this will help you.